Spring Boot Config Client Issue on Java 21, Boot 3.3.2
I have a simple sample spring boot application that works as expected in java 8, but doesnt when upgraded to java 21.
Here is the context.
I have a local config server setup using native profile and the following profile path (example) for search locations
 searchLocations: file:///C:/config/repo/shared/{profile},file:///C:/config/repo/{application},file:///C:/config/repo/{application}/{profile},file:///C:/config/local/

I have an application example-app, whose application yaml, looks like
spring:
  application:
    name: example-app
  profiles.include: example-profile
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888   # The URL of the config server
      fail-fast: true               # Fails fast if config server is not reachable

server:
  port: 8080


So my expectation is to load example-profile contents from the above search location and apply overrides as application when same profile is present in more than one location.
But the behavior is diff in java 8 vs 21. In java 8, if the same profile exists in two locations, the last  occurrence on the file path above replaces first, say, file from local will override that under shared. This works as expected in java 8, but when on 21, it just takes the contents from first occurrence and doesnt do the override part.
when i do /actuator/env/propertya,
in java 8, it would list local folder as where it picks the content from
in java 21, it would list as shared.
Why is this the case? are there any additional libraries or config that are need to make this work as expected in java 21.
my pom xml is
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>config-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator for monitoring purposes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Cloud Starter Config for Config Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven compiler plugin to use Java 21 -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

There arent any java other than the main application, (and application yaml above) which is

package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ConfigClientApplication {

    // This property will be fetched from the config server
    @Value("${message:Default message}")
    private String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}


To test on java 8, change
boot version to 2.6.2
cloud version to 2021.0.0
maven compiler plugin to 3.8.1

Running the app via IntelliJ IDE community edition.
